# Does the sum of all being exist itself?

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request

Can we conceptually build the (mereological) “sum” of “all being” / “everything that exists” without running into problems or paradoxes?

Can we think of the resulting concept (sometimes called “Being”, capitalized) as referring to an existing thing itself – which means it also belongs to “everything that exists”?

Because for typical, restricted collections this is not the case. The “sum of all cats” is not a cat itself.

It works for mass nouns like “water” (“the sum of all water” is itself water). Or in case of rather unnatural constructions like “the parts of the Eiffel tower” (assuming we regard the Eiffel tower as a part of itself) – which we can ignore since they start from the whole object as given.

So why does it work for “being”? Why is it so obvious, without any justification, that “being” behaves completely unproblematically according to ordinary mass noun “logic”?

Are there any critics of the concept of the “sum of all being” as an existing thing itself?

Comment: Clearly, "the world” is not the totality of "everything" that "exists" because people talk about many worlds and typically do not include sets, numbers and the like. So both "everything" and "exists" are qualified. The latter typically to physical existence only, or less than that, like the observable universe, so the Cantorian problem does not arise at all. The sentence does not carry the burden of defining, it is just a pointer to whatever is physically out there. However, see [Williamson's Everything](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3840881) on defending unqualified use of "everything".

Comment: @Conifold I took it from Wikipedia `In its most general sense, the term "world" refers to the totality of entities, to the whole of reality or to everything that was, is and will be.` So what would be the correct term? “Being”? “Reality”? All those terms have different nuances of meaning…

Comment: There is no "correct" term (i.e. one that faces this problem). All of those are implicitly qualified and/or non-definitional. This problem is specific to mathematical terms that are "defined into existence" with only explicit qualifications, if any.

Comment: @Conifold I didn’t claim it faced that problem – just something roughly analogous. “The world” is sometimes described as “a mereological fusion of everything in it” (Achille Varzi). Or sometimes as the totality of contingent truths. Anyway, we pack a lot into this “world” (and seemingly even more into “Being” or “reality”), so it’s a bit surprising that such constructions yield no inconsistencies.

Comment: Well, we need no type distinctions and explosion of classical logic to get to the paradox. Neither is a feature of natural reasoning. Even mild type stratification, as in [Quine's NF](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine-nf/#TypeTheoAxioNF), provides a non-paradoxical universal set. Williamson sketches how to manage "absolute everything" in a non-paradoxical fashion too, based on higher order logic, which is also no stranger to natural reasoning. So it is not *that* surprising. Indications are that the paradox is an artifact of particularly rigid and narrow logical devices.

Comment: I agree with Conifold here; your definition of "the world" is super sketchy in a few different schools of thought, especially the religious. Virtually all major religious philosophies posit a higher world we cannot access. Those who subscribe to the Many Worlds Interpretation of quantum physics would say there are an infinite number of worlds we cannot access. The world, for these people, is "the totality of everything that exists **that we can interact with**".

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic it’s not surprising that “world” (or “Being”) is context-depending. This question is not about the usage of those words, but if the concept of “Everything” as an existing thing in its own right is unproblematic.

Comment: @viuser I agree; but it's not about the usage of words. If "everything" refers to everything **we can interact with**, it's not a universal set, because we're excluding the unknown.

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic the idea behind the question is: does the sum (I guess mereological fusion) of “everything” (a sensible “everything” which may be restricted) always exist itself in the sense of belonging to “everything”, too? For more restricted collections than “everything” it is very common to not be true:  “every continent” => the sum is the non-island landmass of the world, not a continent in itself.

Comment: What are you? Your physical body, your consciousness, your brain? Are you not the sum of all the cells in your body?? Are you not the sum of all the individual lives of your cells? When 'I" interact with 'You' am I interacting with each cell on an individual basis? Are you a paradox?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda yeah sure, but I’m not a cell. Nothing paradoxical here. It’s the simple question why “being” should behave like things we describe with mass nouns.

Comment: @Conifold an article by someone not biased towards the generality of “everything” would be nice…

Comment: There is a predicativist argument against self-inclusive comprehension. If we are "building" a "world" rather than intend to refer to what is already in place then a concept to be defined should not presuppose itself or concepts defined in terms of it on pain of circularity, see e.g. [Linnebo, On the permissibility of impredicative comprehension](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/70827/2/Hale-HO.pdf).

Comment: See also a collection of papers in the [Absolute Generality volume](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/absolute-generality/) that discuss various problems with quantification over "absolutely everything".